Armour plate with curved edges and raised border
I am trying to replicate an armour plate of a cannon - it is a flat surface, with straight lines and curves and has a raised border, with rivets along its border.
I have tried various ways of doing this - I've attempted to trace vertices that I've extruded to form the shape of the plate.
However, I feel challenged when realising that I need to fill in the shape with vertices to create a shaped plane.
I have also tried creating a plane and subdividing it and then deforming it with proportional editing, but still doesn't look right, because then you have vertices overlapping each other within the outer curved sections etc.
Also, the main problem is also the fact that I need to create the raised border. But I supposed that I would need to ensure that the edges follow the curved perimeter, so I'm able to extrude the border outwards?
I've also tried to forget about the plane and started with skinning an outer edge to create the border. But then... how do you fill in the plate with vertices to make it solid?
The image shows the technique I used to "fill" in the plane with vertices, after skinning the border. But the distribution of vertices in the plane I have done manually and doesn't look right.


I've used an image from your screen as a background image.
Start with a single Vertex and E (Extrude) round the periphery of your image using F to fill the final edge.

Hit A to select All then F to create a face.

Go into Face mode and use I (inset) to create your surround

Then Ctrl-I to invert the selection followed by Alt-E > Extrude Faces along Normals checking Offset Even if necessary on the bottom-left Operator menu


Thank you for the answer. I haven't attempted your technique yet, but I am just concerned about one thing: - When the face is filled in. How is is filled in? As an Ngon? I would like to have an evenly distributed mesh so that I don't run into unwanted artefacts when rendering. Also, what if I want to add details in the face? I would need some sort of topology in an evenly distributed series of vertices in the mesh to be able to work on. Not sure if I've explained myself correctly... Thanks

It would be filled as a single face but you can subdivide the face that's left after creating the surrounding edge. I wouldn't worry about artefacts or evenly distributing vertices if the face itself is flat. They shouldn't be visible when it's rendered.
